Is there any way to simulate a larger sector size on Windows 11?
I am looking into some issues that have been reported when installing software to Windows 11 running on a laptop with 16k-sector drive. As my laptop's drive has 4k sectors, I am wondering if there is a way to simulate the problem environment (instead of purchasing a physical drive).

Not sure you can set allocation unit size (or that it would be meaningful), but would a RAM drive work? https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/

@John I removed the need for it being an SSD.

@Joep van Steen 16k is what the customer reported. At one point, I had access to a drive with 8k sectors but no longer do.

Yes, that link is exactly the problem. The install tries to install SQL Server and fails.

@DrMoishe Pippik Thabks for the link. It doesn’t look like that will work, but I’ll have to review it  more closely, and it provided a link to another project that also merits further review.

@SaulRowe - The article indicates the output of fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo E: would provide the information you seek.  Just change the drive letter of the drive in question.

@Ramhound Thanks, that's how I confirmed the drive had 4k sectors. I need to have 8k or higher.

@Joep van Steen Thanks for those links. I was just thinking that I may just get an external drive with the larger sector size since I'm not finding any way to simulate it.
